# unique div ids with every link_to_add in a nested_form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

```
## NO-AJAX, No filtering
# Since there is no filtering, it lists all the orders.
##
# partial:
<%= f.collection_select(:customer, @customers,
  :customer_id, :customer_name, {:prompt=>'Select a Customer'})
%>
<%= f.collection_select(:order_id, @orders,
  :order_id, :order_name, {:prompt=>'Select an Order'} )
%>

# view:
<%= nested_form_for @service do |f| %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "Add Order", :orders %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>

#controller:
def new
  @service = Service.new
  @service.orders.build
  @customers = Customer.find(:all)
  @orders = Order.find(:all)
end


## Q: BUT I WANT TO DO filtering based on the customer select, with AJAX and update the  div accordingly.  
# partial:
<%= f.collection_select(:customer, @customers,
  :customer_id, :customer_name, {:prompt=>'Select a Customer'})%>
<div id='display'></div>
```

Here is my question: With each link_to_add, i'd like to create a unique "display" div, because i have a javascript that populates that "display" div with the onchange event of that collection_select. 
Thanks for the helps!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the following code will create unique divs every time you click the link.

**HTML**:
​

```
<a href="#" id="link_to_add">Link to Add</a>

​<div id="parent_div">
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**jQuery**:

```
var divCnt = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#link_to_add').click(function(){
        $('#parent_div').html($('#parent_div').html()+'<div id="display_'+divCnt+'">Display div '+divCnt+'</div>');
        divCnt++;
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!    ​